# android swf problem

Tags: android

Hi swf can be loaded successfully in debug mode, but i cannot see any swf loaded in runtime or maybe couple of time it can load swf, and sometimes just the black screen.

This is how I load swf in my web view, any ideas?

```
WebView mWebView1 = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.image);
        mWebView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView1.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);           
        mWebView1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1.swf");
```

Comment: When it does not work, check the LogCat for errors...

Comment: nothing in the logCat. it just sometimes show the swf, sometimes nothing and sometimes blackscreen in the place of web view

Comment: If I load any url from web it shows in runtime too, I guess there is problem in assets folder but what?